# Merging 2 arrays into 1 in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Okay so i have this following exercise i need to merge 2 arrays together into 1 array.

---

The new array has to containt elements of each array e.g: newArray index 0 = array1Element from 0 index,  newArray index 1 = array2Element from index 0 and so on..

If one of those arrays has no more elements, continue putting elements from the longer array... so far i have come to this..which is of not right or isn't giving the right solution..can you please give me a proper solution and explain everything that was done in the code..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array1 = {1,1,1,1,1,1};
    int[] array2 = {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2};
    arrayMan(array1,array2);
}

public static int[] arrayMan(int[] firstArray,int[] secondArray) {
    int[] newArray = new int[firstArray.length + secondArray.length];
    int array1Pos;
    int array2Pos;
    System.arraycopy(firstArray,0,newArray,0,firstArray.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length -1 ; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < secondArray.length ; j++) {
            if(newArray[i] == newArray[i+1]) {
                array1Pos = newArray[i+1];
                array2Pos = secondArray[j];
                    newArray[i] = array1Pos;
                    newArray[i + 1] = array2Pos;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length ; i++) {
        System.out.println(newArray[i]);
    }


    return newArray;
}
```

The expected output should be {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2}

Comment: Sorry, but this site is not a free "we debug your code for you" service. A) if your program is not delivering the expected output, then include descriptions of that failure in your question and B) learn how to use a debugger; or simply add trace statements into your logic ... so you enable **yourself** to hunt down the problems in **your** code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What does your code output and what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: @Paul the output should be {1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,2}

Comment: @AndroidMegaman So do you know what is meant by sorting 2 arrays into 1? If it is sorting then the output should be {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2}. Please change the title to more appropriate one.

Answer (score 3):

I won't write the code for you but I'll try to point you in the right direction.

I think you would find it helpful to first do this on paper, writing out the state after each number is added to the destination array.

For example:

```
Start:
sourceArray1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1]
sourceArray2 = [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
targetArray = []
targetIndex = 0  <- where to put the next item
source1Index = 0  <- where to get the next item from sourceArray1
source2Index = 0  <- where to get the next item from sourceArray2

Step (take from sourceArray1)
targetArray = [1]
targetIndex = 1
source1Index = 1
source2Index = 0

Step (take from sourceArray2)
targetArray = [1,2]
targetIndex = 2
source1Index = 1
source2Index = 1

Step (take from sourceArray1)
targetArray = [1,2,1]
targetIndex = 3
source1Index = 2
source2Index = 1
```

Keep doing this until `targetArray` is filled. At some point you won't be able to increment `source1Index` and will have to draw exclusively from `sourceArray2`.

Once you understand how to do this on paper you'll find the code much easier to write (and you'll see there's no need for `System.arrayCopy`).